# When is the "literary theory" tag appropriate for a PhilosophySE post?

Tags: discussion

The [IEP article on literary theory](https://iep.utm.edu/literary/) says:

> By literary theory we refer not to the meaning of a work of literature but to the theories that reveal what literature can mean. Literary theory is a description of the underlying principles, one might say the tools, by which we attempt to understand literature. All literary interpretation draws on a basis in theory but can serve as a justification for very different kinds of critical activity. It is literary theory that formulates the relationship between author and work; literary theory develops the significance of race, class, and gender for literary study, both from the standpoint of the biography of the author and an analysis of their thematic presence within texts. Literary theory offers varying approaches for understanding the role of historical context in interpretation as well as the relevance of linguistic and unconscious elements of the text. Literary theorists trace the history and evolution of the different genres—narrative, dramatic, lyric—in addition to the more recent emergence of the novel and the short story, while also investigating the importance of formal elements of literary structure. Lastly, literary theory in recent years has sought to explain the degree to which the text is more the product of a culture than an individual author and in turn how those texts help to create the culture.

Are philosophical questions about the logical value of semiotics, including typography, or about the structure of meaning in fiction novels, examples of the philosophy of literary theory, then? I don't see how it could be otherwise. For example, suppose that the boundary between literary theory and philosophy of literature directly, is a vague one. Vagueness is something better understood among philosophers, I suspect. It is, oddly, a less ambiguous term, here, whatever the interior enigma of vague phenomena may be. Moreover, certainly it seems as though **knowing a lot of examples of literature through and through, would be quite relevant to forming a substantial literary theory of any kind whatsoever**. So suppose someone has read:

1. All ten Thomas Covenant novels.
2. 6 Mistborn, 4 Stormlight Archive, and 3 other Cosmere novels (plus 1 graphic novel (plus Sanderson's *A Memory of Light*).
3. The Nausicaä graphic novels.
4. *V for Vendetta* and *Watchmen.*
5. Dante's *Purgatorio* and *Paradiso* (but perhaps not *Inferno*, oddly).
6. Milton's *Paradise Lost* and *Paradise Regained*. [Btw, bonus points if you have a thesis, perhaps not unprecedented, according to which the content of PR retroactively diminishes the "illusion of Satanism" in PL.]
7. Michael Ende's *The Neverending Story.*
8. By Umberto Eco: *The Name of the Rose*, *Foucault's Pendulum*, *The Island of the Day Before*, *The Prague Cemetery*, *Baudolino*, and *The Mysterious Flame of Queen Loana*.
9. By Mark Z. Danielewski: *House of Leaves*, *Only Revolutions*, *The Little Blue Kite*, and The Familiar, vol. 1 through 5.
10. Hofstader's GEB (a right good vague example).
11. *The Last Unicorn.*
12. J. R. R. Tolkien's *The Hobbit*, *The Silmarillion*, and *The Lord of the Rings.*
13. Too many Stephen King books to remember.
14. Several Peter Straub novels (esp. *lost boy lost girl*).
15. *The City at the End of Time* and *Anvil of Stars* (among others of Greg Bear's works).
16. The Children of the Last Days books (minus 1 of the total).
17. *The Last of the Just*.
18. *Childhood's End.*
19. His Dark Materials.
20. Vaguely further numbers of miscellaneous cases of fiction (mostly science fiction or fantasy, e.g. almost all of Lovecraft's Cthulhu stories).

Couple this with a lot of history books/articles (mostly democide studies/international law, but then incl. esp. *The Origins of Totalitarianism* and, for another "literary" example, *The Gulag Archipelago*; but also primarily, altogether, such as pertain to the Vietnam War), Kant's three Critiques + *Religion within the Limits of Reason Alone* and then Neiman, O'Neill, Korsgaard, and Wood's major commentaries, besides also John Rawls' *A Theory of Justice*, most of the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, lots of fictionalistic-seeming set-theory articles (in the sense that set theory makes a case for mathematical fictionalism better than almost any other kind of mathematics), Guy and Conway's *The Book of Numbers*, several journalism-style books about physics (incl. by physicists, e.g. Brian Greene), some (very limited) practical experience with programming/scripting languages, familiarity with a wide range of formal logics, an assortment of miscellaneous essays on ethical philosophy (a few dozen or scores or so of these, let's say), all this along with knowledge of various scriptures (not many, all things considered, and often pretty much in only one language at all) and (many, many more) esp. Christian theological treatises? If the boundary between literary theory and philosophy about literature might be vague, so too might be the boundary between literature itself and other compositional forms on the same level. At any rate, if one ought to know a lot of literature and a lot of philosophy to talk philosophically, and hence theoretically, about literature, it would help to know even more than such as was imagined above, although the above would make for quite a good start, let us suppose.